# REGEXP_REPLACE replace spaces between two symbols

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I need to replace all spaces with one % between two specific symbols (@ and &); like followings:

```
'this @ is test   &that did not @turn& out well'
```

should be converted to

```
'this @%is%test%&that did not @turn& out well'
```

and

```
'@pattern matching&  is my number one enemy'
```

to

```
'@pattern%matching&  is my number one enemy'
```

I almost read all related questions in stackoverflow and other sites but couldn't get a helpful answer.

Comment: Please share the code that fails for you. The most recent attempt to solve the problem would do.

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('@ M j &test','@( )(.*)()@','@% %&')

Comment: Ok, I see. The issue here is that you cannot use two patterns as start and end delimiters to search for multiple matches in-between with PostgreSQL regex. It is possible in other regex flavors either thanks to infinite width lookbehind or `\G` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (inefficient) way of doing this is by doing multiple `REGEXP_REPLACE` calls.

For example, lets look at the following `plpgsql` function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replaceSpacesBetweenTwoSymbols(startChar TEXT, endChar TEXT, textToParse TEXT)
    RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
DECLARE resultText TEXT := textToParse;
DECLARE tempText TEXT := textToParse;
BEGIN
    WHILE TRUE LOOP
        tempText = REGEXP_REPLACE(resultText,
                                  '(' || startChar || '[^' || endChar || ']*)' || '( )(.*' || endChar || ')',
                                  '\1%\3');
        IF tempText = resultText
        THEN RETURN resultText;
        END IF;
        resultText := tempText;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN resultText;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

We create a function that takes three arguments, the `startChar`, the `endChar` and the `textToParse` which holds the text that will be trimmed.

We start by creating a a regular expression based on the `startChar` and `endChar`. If the value of `startChar` is `@` and the value of `endChar` is `&` we will get the following regular expression:

```
(@[^&]*)( )(.*&)
```

This regular expression is consisted of three groups:

1. `(@[^&]*)` - This group matches the text that is between the @ and an an empty space character - ' ';
2. `( )` - This group matches a single space character.
3. `(.*&)` - This group matches the text that is between a space character and the `&` character.

In order to replace the space (group 2), we use the following `REGEXP_REPLACE` call:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(resultText,' (@[^&]*)( )(.*&)', '\1%\3')
```

From that expression you can see that we are replacing the second group (which is a space) with the `%` character.

This way, we will only replace one space per one `REGEXP_REPLACE` execution.
Once we find that there are no more spaces that need to be replaced, we return the modified `TEXT`.

At this moment, the spaces are replaced with `%` characters. One last thing we need to do is to replace the multiple consecutive `%` characters with a single `%`.

That can be done with another `REGEXP_REPLACE` call at the end.
So for example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(replaceSpacesBetweenTwoSymbols('@','&','this @ is test   &that did not @turn& out well'),'%{2,}','%');
```

Will return

> this @%is%test%&that did not @turn& out well

as a result, while this

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(replaceSpacesBetweenTwoSymbols('@','&','this is @a more  complex& task @test a a & w'),'%{2,}','%');
```

will return

> this is @a%more%complex& task @test%a%a%& w

as a result.

Comment: Best answer ever! Thank you. I used the code with a little changes